# Why spark arises on electrical junction box

Tags: power-supply, power, low-power, power-dissipation

A week ago lightning occurred in my area and computer monitor got burnt. From months the fuse producing sound whenever i turn on any home application, is the fuse weak ? And what is the cause of electrical spark , what I am asking is which one makes the device damage , the earth connection or phase or neutral. Or the combination of any of these. Am scared to plug my smartphone because of these , help me out

Excuse if any wrong in question

Comment: A fuse won't produce sound. You are probably mistaken.

Comment: If you think you have a fault with your home electrics you should call a qualified electrician to check it out for you. Messing with things you don't understand can cause your house to burn down.

Comment: @andy aka no bro , my home is 100 year old... So the wiring is old..... Whenever I turn on the application it producing "tip " sound like crackers do.... Examine the terms I need to know what's happening in electrical connections

Comment: If your fusebox makes noise under ANY conditions you need an electrician. Either that, or you need to take out a large insurance policy on your house so that you'll be covered when it burns down or someone gets electrocuted. You do not "need to know what's happening in electrical connections" except to know that you have a problem which may kill you. Get a professional, and do it now. No arguments, no backtalk, no putting it off. Do it.

Answer (score 3):

If your house wiring hasn't been inspected/repaired by a qualified electrician since the lightning damage occurred, then there is almost guaranteed to be damage to your wiring that can cause danger to yourself, your home, and your electronics.

If you are hearing crackling noises from your fusebox whenever you use an appliance, that could very well mean that the insulation on your wires was melted/scorched during the lightning surge, and is allowing electric to short-circuit spark between wires. *THAT CAN START A HOUSE FIRE!*

Please, for your own safety, have your house elerical system inspected & tell the inspector about the lightning **AND** the noises from the fusebox. They can check to find where you have unsafe wires, so you can have them, or another electrician, fix the problems and make your home safe again.